# ios how to create a toolbar button with a popup button

Tags: uitoolbar, uisegmentedcontrol, uitoolbaritem

I'm trying to create a toolbar like the one in [tweetbot](http://tapbots.com/img/software/tweetbot/icon_tabbar.png) where if you press a button in the tool bar - more buttons pop up above it vertically.
I tried using a uisegmented control and rotating it 90 degrees but it looks really bad. Does any one know a way to do it the right way?